# Is it possible to wildcard filter a Pyspark Data Frame using a named variable?

Tags: python, pyspark

I have created a variable that I would like to use in a wildcard filter on a PySpark DataFrame. I'm able to use the variable name for an exact match, but I'm not sure how to incorporate the variable name in a wildcard search.

This code works for me just fine, however it will only pull results that are an exact match with variable. I need this to work for a wildcard filter.

```py
variable = variablename

df = df.filter(df.columnName.like(variable))
```

I've tried adding "%" before and after, but this does not accomplish a wildcard search like I'd hope.

```py
variable = filtername
df = df.filter(df.columnName.like(%variable%))
```

When I try this, I get

```py
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Is it possible to wildcard search a variable name? How can I accomplish this?

Comment: `df.filter(df.columnName.like("%{}%".format(variable)))` or `df.filter(df.columnName.like("%" + variable + "%"))`

Comment: @pault thank you, the first option worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@pault comment did the trick and solved my problem.

```py
df.filter(df.columnName.like("%{}%".format(variable)))
```